# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property postDao has not been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error and the data is not getting added in Firebase.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var postDao: PostDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        add.setOnClickListener {
            val input1 = enterAmount.text.toString().trim()
            val input2 = spendLocation.text.toString().trim()
            if(input1.isNotEmpty() && input2.isNotEmpty()){
//                if(this::postDao.isInitialized){
                    postDao.addPost(input1,input2)
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Post.kt**

```
data class Post (
    val amount: String = "",
    val createdBy: User = User(),
    val createdAt: Long = 0L,
    val locate: String = "")
```

**PostDao.kt**

```
class PostDao {
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val postCollections = db.collection("posts")
    private val auth = Firebase.auth

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun addPost(text1:String, text2: String){
        val currentUserId = auth.currentUser!!.uid
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val userDao = UserDao()
            val user = userDao.getUserById(currentUserId).await().toObject(User::class.java)!!
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val post = Post(text1, user, currentTime,text2)
            postCollections.document().set(post)
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spendAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:text="@string/spend_amount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterAmount"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:autofillHints="5000"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spendAmount"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spendOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/location"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterAmount" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/spendLocation"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:autofillHints="5000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spendOn"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spendLocation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.cashmates'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cashmates"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

**The error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cashmates, PID: 6495
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property postDao has not been initialized
        at com.example.cashmates.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at com.example.cashmates.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$YuF2DVJARYM7PHZ7pfZptdE8pU4(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.cashmates.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7507)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7484)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:839)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28689)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

I tried to add the strings and corresponding time and user ID in the Firebase. but it resulted in an error and nothing got added in the Firebase and the app crashed.

Comment: `lateinit` means you're promising to initialize the property before using it, but you're not initializing it anywhere. You can't use something that doesn't exist. In this case, your class isn't dependent on anything (it has an empty constructor) so there's no reason you need to initialize it late anyway. You can just initialize it at the declaration site.

Comment: can you please tell me what should I write instead of "postDao.addPost(input1,input2)" if I remove "private lateinit var postDao: PostDao"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property postDao has not been initialized

Because you have declared the following field:

```
private lateinit var postDao: PostDao
```

As `lateinit` but you have never initialized it. This also means that the following statement:

```
if(this::postDao.isInitialized)
```

Will always return false because the `postDao` field is never initialized.

As also @Tenfour04 mentioned in his comment, there is no need to define that variable as `lateinit`. So to avoid such an error, you have to initialize directly.

Comment: can you please tell me how to initialize directly?

Comment: Try like this: `val postDao = PostDao()`. Does it work now?